# Unable to make use of links to fetch different titles

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, promise, request, cheerio

I've created a script in `node` using `promise` in combination with `request` and `cheerio` to parse the `links` under `Province` column from this [webpage](https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/p/all) then reuse those links to scrape all the urls under `Office` column from all of such [pages](https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/p/Cairo) and finally make use these `links` to collect the `title` from all of such [target pages](https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/Cairos-main), as in `Cairos main Post Office` in this page.

My current script most of the times gets stuck. However, sometimes it throws this error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`. I've checked each of the functions and found that they are all working in the right way individually.

Although the script looks a bit bigger, it is built upon a very simple logic which is make use of each `links` from it's landing page until it reaches the `title` of it's target page.

This is my try so far:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/p/all';
const base_link = 'https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/';

const items = [];
const nitems = [];

let getLinks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (error) return reject(error);
            try {
                $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                    items.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
                });
                resolve(items);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
};

let getData = (links) => {
    const promises = links
        .map(nurl => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(nurl, function(error, response, html) {
                let $ = cheerio.load(html);
                if (error) return reject(error);
                try {
                    $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
                        nitems.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
                    });
                    resolve(nitems);
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            })
        }))

    return Promise.all(promises)
}

let FetchData = (links) => {
    const promises = links
        .map(nurl => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request(nurl, function(error, response, html) {
                let $ = cheerio.load(html);
                if (error) return reject(error);
                try {
                    resolve($(".home-title > h2").eq(0).text());
                } catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            })
        }))

    return Promise.all(promises)
}

getLinks().then(resultList => {
    getData(resultList).then(resultSet => {
        FetchData(resultSet).then(title =>{
            console.log(title);
        })
    })
})
```

> ***How can I scrape the titles from target pages making use of all the links from landing pages?***

Comment: Please be gentle to the server you are scrapping from, it cannot handle hundreds of requests at the same time, that's why your script got stuck. For the `Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`, you should check `if(error)` first then do the `cheerio.load`.

Comment: Broher, I got whats the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue is with `2D` array. If you go through carefully over your `getData` function, you're returning 2D array.

`map` return an array and within that map you're resolving another array `nitems`.

Here's the working code:

```
const base_link = 'https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/';

// helper wrapper DRY
const getHtmls = (url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({ uri: url, method: 'GET', followAllRedirects: true } , function(error, response, html) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      else resolve(html);
    });
  })
}

let getLinks = async () => {
  const link = 'https://www.egyptcodebase.com/en/p/all';
  const items = [];
  try {
    const html = await getHtmls(link);
    let $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
      items.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // handling error here so execution can continue for good eggs
    console.error(e.message)
  }
  return items;
};

let getData = async (links) => {
  const out = [];
  try {
    const promises = links.map(nurl => getHtmls(nurl));

    const htmls = await Promise.all(promises);
    htmls.forEach(html => {
      let $ = cheerio.load(html);
      $('.table tbody tr').each(function() {
        out.push(base_link + $(this).find("a").attr("href"));
      });
    })
  } catch (e) {
    // handling error here so execution can continue for good eggs
    console.error(e.message)
  }
  return out;
}

let FetchData = async (links) => {
  const out = [];
  try {
    const promises = links.map(nurl => getHtmls(nurl));
    const htmls = await Promise.all(promises)
    htmls.forEach(html => {
      try {
        let $ = cheerio.load(html);
        out.push($(".home-title > h2").eq(0).text());
      } catch (e){
        // handling error here so execution can continue for good eggs
        console.error(e.message)
      }
    })
  } catch (e) {
    // handling error here so execution can continue for good eggs
    console.error(e.message)
  }
  return out;
}

getLinks().then(resultList => {
  getData(resultList).then(resultSet => {
    FetchData(resultSet).then(title =>{
      console.log(title);
    })
  })
})
```

Note: Instead of writing your own `Promise` wrapper, you could use `request-promise` package

Comment: I rectified my script just the way you suggested and ran it. However, it still gets stuck. After execution, I waited for any result for hours but it didn't print anything @1556089774. Can you suggest where I'm going wrong? This is [the rectified script](https://pastebin.com/fVg44mHX). Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt updated answer, check (I couldn't test for all ~540 links, network issue), let me know if it's working

Comment: I waited for half an hour after executing your suggested script but it still hangs. Should I've waited more? I'm gonna award this bounty on your answer and I hope you will take a look what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt some refactoring and some changes, tested and working (looks like some htmls does not have `".home-title > h2"` `' Exhibits Island Post Office', ' Kafr Moyes Post Office', '',` notice the third entry is empty string in single quotes). Tested on all ~540 urls. Also looks like server cannot handle the load. (frequent connection reset) @SamyMassoud sorry for bombarding your site, had to do it to test :)

Answer (score 3):

It would be much easier to ask the website Owner about the data which you need.
He might understand your request and give it to you for free, instead of scraping his site.

> P.S: I was surprised to find a question about how to **scrape** my own website.
> P.S2: If you just need all post office titles I could have given it for you for free :D
> P.S3: Your error is maybe happening because of some time the page doesn't have the element which you are trying to parse using cheerio.

Comment: I'm not after the data at all. I used the link as an example site. All I wish to know is the way to achieve what I've been trying @Samy Massoud.

Comment: @robots.txt Then check P.S3 and print the content which you have got to make sure  the item you are looking for does exist in the html

Comment: World is a small place! Haha :D

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is in FetchData function, as in that function you are passing links and then using map over it. 
But if you look inside that map function and check the value of 'nurl' variable it will be an array of links and its data type would be object.
According to the semantics of request function, its first param should be string, so if you iterate over the 'nurl' variable to get the values, then it would work.

[My code snippet for one url from array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mftZ4.png)